# Why is this MySQL query taking so long and how can I fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

When I have about 30 actors this query is taking 20+ seconds. Is there a way to speed this up dramatically? I am sure there is, I just don't know in what way or where to start.

```
  REPEAT
    FETCH actors INTO a;
      IF a != '' THEN
        IF !(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movieactor WHERE actor = a) THEN
          INSERT INTO movieactor (actor) 
          VALUES (a);
         END IF;
      END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;
```

`movieactor` table has just an `actor` and an `id`.

Comment: Is actor indexed?  How many records are in the movieactor table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to show the table definitions, indexes, query plan, and triggers to understand performance.  However, this query has some obvious suggestions.

Why not use set operations, such as:

```
insert into movieactor(actor)
    select a
    from actors
    where a <> '' and
          a not in (select * from (select actor from movieactor))
```

(The double select is something that I think is needed for MySQL to parse this.)

Second, you should have an index on movieactor.actor.  That will probably speed up the query a lot.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't have an index on actors. Stupid mistake. Thank you!